React DndKit, item gets added to the drop area even if just clicked. isOver is not activated only on the drop area
This is the main page. I have a list of draggable items that I display in a list.
Whenever I click  any of those, without moving it, it gets added to the drop area.
event.over is activated everytime i click.
Should the default behavior be so that when I leave the item on the droparea, only then the over should be activated and then we should have the id of the drop area event.over.id>
This is the code of my main page:
export default function Home() {
    const [items, setItems] = useState<ItemProps[]>(Items);
    const [dropped, setDropped] = useState<ItemProps[]>([]);


    const onDragEnd  = (event: any) => {
        console.log("event end", event)
        if (event.over && event.over.id === 'dropsite-1') {
           console.log('alert')
        }
    }

    const onDragOver = (event: any) => {
        console.log("event over" ,event)
    }


    const generateRandomId = () => {
        return Math.random().toString(36).substring(7);
    }


  return (
      <DndContext
          collisionDetection={closestCenter}
          id={"context-1"}
          onDragOver={onDragOver}
          onDragEnd={onDragEnd}
      >
          <div className="container">
              <ul className="list-container">
                  {items.map((item) => (
                      <Draggable id={item.id} item={item} key={item.id}/>
                  ))}
              </ul>
              <Droppable items={dropped} id="dropsite-1"/>
          </div>
      </DndContext>

  );

}

This is the droppable that should later display the listed of dropped items
import { useDroppable } from "@dnd-kit/core";

import {ItemProps} from "@/app/page";
interface DroppableProps {
    items: ItemProps[];
    id: string;
}

export function Droppable({ items, id }: DroppableProps) {
    const { setNodeRef, isOver } = useDroppable({ id: id }); // Use a unique id or derive from props if needed


    return (
            <ul className="list-container" ref={setNodeRef}>
                {items.map((item) => (
                    <li className="list-item" key={item.id}>
                        {item.name}
                    </li>
                ))}
            </ul>
    );
}

And this is the draggable item:
import React from 'react';
import {useDraggable} from '@dnd-kit/core';

import {ItemProps} from "@/app/page";

export function Draggable({item, id}: {item: ItemProps, id: string}) {
    const {attributes, listeners, setNodeRef, transform} = useDraggable({
        id: id,
    });
    const style = transform ? {
        transform: `translate3d(${transform.x}px, ${transform.y}px, 0)`,
    } : undefined;


    return (
        <li  className="list-item" ref={setNodeRef} style={style} {...listeners} {...attributes}>
            {item.name}
        </li>
    );
}

I cannot figure out how to make this work. I would appreciated if you have any input.

That is because you have the collisionDetection set as closestCenter, try with   rectIntersection instead

As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
